# screen disconnects during linux boot until physically reconnected

Tags: linux, boot, hdmi, uefi

I have got an Asrock J4105 mainboard

During the boot, at some point in systemd, the screen goes black (saying no signal) until I take the HDMI cable and remove it and plug it back in. This is what I would like to fix. It does not matter if I remove the cable on the PC or screen side

My screen is an old LG TV. The mainboard supports HDMI 2.0 and only UEFI, not legacy. I checked over the online update function that the BIOS is up to date. The cable is rather old and from amazon basics.

I have tried:

1. Manjaro with Kernels:

   - 4.18.5-1
   - 4.14.67-1 (on which I did all other tests)
   - 4.4.153-1
   - 3.16.57-1 (cannot load gui)
2. Manjaro without a login/display manager
3. Xubuntu live usb
4. Ubuntu Gnome live usb
5. Fedora 28 live usb (wayland)

   And they all show exactly the same behaviour.
6. Furthermore, booting using the nomodeset option works, whereas video=LVDS-1:d, video=HDMI1:d, vga=ask did not work
7. Turning the TV off and on works
8. And **very** rarely it just randomly works
9. VGA cables work (but I would like to have better image quality and cec features...)
10. logging into a console while the screen is off and using xrandr without a login manager, it just says "can't open display"
11. during boot, the screen goes black after saying "TPM self test failed"
12. the hdmi on the TV always worked when I was using it with a raspberry pi 3 B.
13. using startx while the screen is still disconnected does not solve it

and that is all I know. What I would like to try would be to use a different graphics driver, but there is just a ton of stuff installed like the "intal vulkan mesa driver" among others.

I hope that by enumerating this stuff potential answers can be more easily written.

thanks for reading and I'm looking forward to answers or hints. If you want to see some log outputs, I will gladly provide them. I just don't know which one would be relevant.

Kind Regards,
Tobi

---

*note: if anyone who reads this wonders what video=LVDS-1:d and such is about, it can be configured here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-making_temporary_changes_to_a_grub_2_menu and I can get into this "grub2" menu by selecting advanced boot options during the booting process. Afaik those options can be set permanently in /etc/default/grub by adding them to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.*

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor? Can you try booting with `video=1024x768`?

Comment: I don't have another hdmi display. Using video=1024x768 will get me into the terminal for the login as well as lightdm, but when I login, the screen says "No Signal" and replugging will not fix it. The screen got visible though when I used the power button to shut down (shutdown was prevented because of some unimportant message box).

Comment: Maybe there is some weird stuff with wrong automatically detected resolution going on? With the xfce session trying to detect a wrong video mode again, after the video mode got fixed previously.

documentation of https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/fb/modedb.txt says, that there is a database of standard video modes. Maybe I can somehow override the settings for my screen permamently to be my desired resolution of 1280x720. Thanks a lot

Comment: now it suddenly doesn't work anymore. old result even when I set video=1024x768. Between it having effect and having no effect I played around with the stuff from this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution#377944

Comment: I have also tried to set the display mode of lightdm as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/73804/wrong-login-screen-resolution/88882#88882 without any success

Comment: Well, if `video=<X>x<Y>` works for console, that's a good start. Can you try to figure out how to set a fixed resolution via /etc/X11/xorg.conf? (By the way, I don't think the 'modedb' is applicable to modern KMS video drivers at all.)

Comment: I had installed the video-vesa drivers and uninstalled the intel drivers before and figured out this breaks it completely. After reinstalling drivers using "sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300" and removing video-vesa (https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Configure_Graphics_Cards) I was able to do 3 successful boots. I will now try to figure out if any of the changes I did to grub were relevant and if it works with lightdm installed, and if there is a way to force the 1280x720 resolution in the login screen without breaking it again.

Comment: since the issue is apparent in both x11 and wayland, and not with nomodeset, I think it is very likely to be a driver issue, especially with the recent progress on the issue. I'll try tu use my hdmi -> vga adapter on a faulty live stick afterwards (to maybe figure out if all hdmi devices are affected).

Comment: Well... it _might_ be a driver issue, but most likely of the "choosing the wrong video mode" sort, pointed by the fact that manually picking a low resolution avoids the problem. (And `nomodeset` probably works simply because you're using a very low-res video mode, not because you're disabling the rest of the driver.)

Comment: See the answer below. I have got it working now and it definitely is caused by the resolutions. Thank you so much, your tip with video=1024x768 absolutely got us on the right track and the thing with setting xorg.conf (was horribly annoying because I don't want to read a mile long man page to set a default resolution) also helped in the end. Hopefully this thread will help other people in the future as well c:

Answer (score 2):

**steps required that seem to be neccessary to fix it:**

- having the video=1280x720 mode (or probably any other supported resolution) in grub (big thanks to @grawity)
- installing drivers using the "sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300" command from the network
- setting the resolution of the screen in such a way, that it is remembered next time. (Actually the standard manjaro "Display" setting works, as long as the hdmi cable is not unplugged)

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf:**

```
 Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "External HDMI"
    Modeline        "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
    Option          "PreferredMode" "1280x1024_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Intel UHD 600"
    Driver          "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Primary Screen"
    Device          "Intel UHD 600"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Modes   "1280x720"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Default Layout"
        Screen          "Primary Screen"
EndSection
```

driver name "intel" (source: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-config.html)

setting resolutions in xorg.conf https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

generating modeline, I used cvt: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/67282a/is_cvt_or_gtf_better_for_creating_a_48hz_modeline/

thanks to this config file, the resolution defaults to 1280x720 when reconnecting the screen (e.g. because I want to clean the TV & avoiding further reconfiguration steps over the gui to go back to the desired resolution)

the error seems to have been caused by defaulting to a 1920x1080 60hz resolution, which makes the tv go black even when set manually.

**further stuff:**

using an hdmi -> vga D/A converter does not cause problems, so it kinda seems to be some stupid imcompatibility between the TV and the Driver.

lightdm works as well for me and is always set to a 1280x720 resolution now, as well as logging in without a display manager form a console and the "startx" command.

steps that were not affecting it when reversed, after I got it working:

- having "xrandr -s 1280x720" in ./.xprofile
- having "GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console" uncommented in /etc/default/grub
- having "GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep" commented in /etc/default/grub

alternatives:

- using vga instead of hdmi (tested on the same TV)

not yet tested:

- using dvi instead of hdmi

Comment: It is actually not an uncommon problem for monitors to report bogus supported resolutions via EDID, and sometimes people even have to generate a fake EDID because the one from their monitor is utterly wrong. I have one LCD screen that doesn't report its native resolution as supported (so it's stretched and fuzzy no matter what you choose).